# Convert compaq fortran to intel fortran error numerical_libraries

Tags: fortran

I am try to convert compaq fortran to intel fortran code.
I install "intel parallel studio XE 2011 SP1 for windows"
I am using visual studio 2010.
I create new empthy fortran project and add my only file "x.for"
when Build I get the error : "error #7002: Error in opening complied module file.  check INCLUDE path [numerical_libraries].
In the code the line is :

```
USE numerical_libraries
```

I try to search for the "numerical_libraries" or IMSL library but I can't find it install on my pc, where should I find it?
How can I fix this bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That `use` statement certainly suggests that your program is looking for an installation of the [IMSL](http://www.roguewave.com/products/imsl-numerical-libraries/fortran-library.aspx) numerical libraries and the error message is telling you that the compiler can't find the file `numerical_libraries.mod`.  Since the IMSL libraries are a paid-for and optional 
component the most likely explanation is that you have not paid for and installed those libraries.

If you have, contact IMSL for some help, that's one of the things you pay for.

If you have not installed those libraries then the easy solution is to pay for them and install them.  [Intel](http://software.intel.com/en-us/rogue-wave-imsl-fortran-library) is one source, RogueWave is another.

A more difficult solution is to identify the IMSL routines which your program calls, and to replace those calls with calls to routines that you do have code for, either from another source or from your own efforts.

**EDIT** in response to OP's comment.

OK, if you do have the libraries you need to do 2 things:

1. Tell the compiler where to find the `.mod` file it needs.  In Visual Studio open the project properties page, navigate to the Fortran/General sub-page and insert the path to `numerical_libraries.mod` into **Additional Include Directories**.
2. Tell the linker where to find the binaries to link to.  In the project properties page open the Linker/General sub-page, put the path to the binaries (either `.lib` or `.dll` files) into **Additional Library Directories**.  On the Linker/Input page include the libraries you want to link to under the heading **Additional Dependencies**.

Then, as they say, *Bob's your mother's brother*.

Comment: I can see the numerical_libraries.mod in C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\DF98\IMSL\INCLUDE